# String to int then change background

Tags: java, string

I'd like some help with my  colorchooser. Alright so what I'm going to do is to type in rgb color lite 255,255,0 in 3 text fields. then i need to convert them to int's and last change the background color. Now the problev is that i get some errors when im clicking on the OK button.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource()==ok){
        int rgb = Integer.parseInt (text1.getText());
        int rgb1 = Integer.parseInt (text2.getText());
        int rgb2 = Integer.parseInt (text3.getText());
        v.setBackground(new Color(rgb, rgb1, rgb2));
}
```

this yields: *Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)*

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please put your stacktrace.

Comment: Debug the code and see what does rgb variables and text variables contains. By the exception I would guess that one of the textboxes are empty.

Comment: Or maybe you're trying to parse a character string instead of an int string

Answer (score 3):

Your logcat clearly says that your are trying to convert empty string to Integer.

```
AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

i.e  you are passing

```
int color=Integer.parseInt("");  // this cause exception.
```

**Make sure that your textfields have number in them.**  , provide validation for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try debugging text1/text2/text3 text variables and see what they hold runtime. If that doesn't help try to set the variables and see that SetBackground works as supposed.